# When configuring a salt-syndic, what should the value of 'master' be in the minion config file?

Tags: salt-stack

When configuring a salt-syndic, what should the value of 'master' be 'localhost' or 'master_of_masters' in the minion config file?

localhost = the loopback address of the syndic itself

OR

master_of_masters = the dns address of the master of masters

Answer (score 0):

> 'Each syndic connected to an upper-level master will have both the
>   salt-master and the salt-syndic daemon running, and optionally, the
>   salt-minion daemon.'

- Source:
  http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/topology/syndic.html#topology

The answer is it doesn't really matter because minion is optional.

Comment: Yes, it's your choice which master will control the minion.